# If result returns null return everything

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause, window-functions

I have the following dataset

```
ID    |   GROUP   |   ORGANIZATION   |     USERNAME
----------------------------------------------------
1          G1            ORG1               SKYLER
2          G1            ORG1               BRAD
3          G1            ORG1               CHAD
4          G2            ORG1               SKYLER
5          G3            ORG1               THAMIUS
6        (null)          ORG1               KYLE
7          G7            ORG2               TAYLOR
8          G7            ORG2               CLAY
9          G7            ORG2               WILL
10         G8            ORG2               KYLE
```

I then have a query which selects an organization and a username:

```
select group from table where organization = 'ORG1' and username = 'SKYLER'
```

It would return this:

```
 GROUP   
 -------
  G1   
  G2
```

This is what I want returned for this query, but then I have a second scenario. If I go:

```
select group from table where organization = 'ORG1' and username = 'KYLE'
```

It returns null, but what I want is to return all the groups for 'ORG1':

```
 GROUP  
--------
  G1 
  G2    
  G3
```

So basically if I select a user inside of an organization and they have a group assigned to them I want to return the groups. If they have no groups assigned to them, that means they are a kind of "super user" for the organization and it should return G1, G2, and G3 when Kyle is selected. I have tried using IFNULL function but ti doesnt allow for select statements inside of it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `exists`:

```
select distinct grp
from mytable
where organization = 'ORG1' and grp is not null and (
    username = 'SKYLER'
    or exists (
        select 1 
        from mytable 
        where organization = 'ORG1' and username = 'SKYLER' and grp is null
    )
)
```

You can also use window functions, if you are running MySQL 8.0:

```
select distinct grp
from (
    select t.*, max(username = 'KYLE' and grp is null) over() is_admin
    from mytable t
    where organization = 'ORG1' 
) t
where grp is not null and (username = 'KYLE' or is_admin = 1)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac036f7d2e2ffd9844ec0a1b300fdaa4)**

Results for Kyle:

```
grp
G1
G2
G3
```

Results for Skyler:

```
grp
G1
G2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried the solutions, when it is a user who has a group associated with them it returns the row group correctly. If the user has no group associated with it, it returns null instead of all the groups

Comment: @user2924127: my bad. I fixed the queries (and tested them). This appears to do what you want now.

Answer (score 0):

The model of your data is not very clear - what organization and group mean. You should consider splitting the data into 2 tables - one for the relation username - organization and another for organization - group.

Although it makes no much sense to me, the query you are after should be something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `group` FROM `table` WHERE organization IN (SELECT DISTINCT organization FROM `table` WHERE organization = 'ORG1' AND username = 'KYLE')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
If ((select id from table where organization = "org1" and username = "kyle" and group is null) is not null)
   then select distinct group from table where organization = "org1";
else select group from table where organization = "org1" and username = "kyle";
end if;
```